# Вираз "заощаджувати на чомусь"

Tags: вживання-слів

Вираз *"заощаджувати на чомусь"* зустрічала багато разів, але є сумніви щодо того, чи правильно вживати його в українській мові.

Тлумачення із СУМ слова [**заощаджувати**](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaoshhadzhuvaty).
В словнику не зустрічається варіант вживання "заощаджувати на чомусь".

Чи доречно вживати цей вираз?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Порівняймо словникові статті дієслів "заощаджувати" й "економити" - перше дієслово перехідне, друге - перехідне і неперхідне, залежно від синтаксичного значення в реченні. Нижче додамо коментар про зміну дієслівної категорії.

> ЗАОЩА́ДЖУВАТИ, ую, уєш, недок., ЗАОЩА́ДИТИ, джу, диш, док., перех.
>   Зберігати невитраченим, складати, нагромаджувати внаслідок доцільного,
>   дбайливого використання; //  Давати
>   можливість зберігати що-небудь, зменшувати витрати чогось;  //  Не робити чого-небудь зайвого.

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaoshhadzhuvaty)

> ЕКОНОМИТИ, млю, миш; мн. економлять; недок.
>
> 1. перех. Бережливо, ощадливо витрачати що-небудь; // 
>      Давати можливість менше витрачати, зберігати що-небудь.
> 2. неперех., на чому. Мати вигоду від ощадливого використання чого-небудь. Економити на всьому;  //  без додатка. Максимально
>      скорочувати витрати.

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/ekonomyty)

Тепер звернімося до поняття категорії перехідності/неперехідності в дієсловах.

> Перехідність/неперехідність - загальнодієслівна категорія, що виражає
>   відношення дії до об'єкта.
>   Перехідні дієслова називають дію, яка поширюється на об'єкт -
>   конкретний предмет, особу чи іншу якусь істоту: спекти коровай,
>   навчати дітей. Неперехідні дієслова
>   називають дію, що не переходить на предмет: зеленіє ліс, птах летить.
>   Чіткої межі між перехідними і неперехідними дієсловами
>   немає. Деякі перехідні можуть вживатися в значенні неперехідних:
>   читати книгу, писати речення (перехідні) - читати вголос, писати
>   повільно (неперехідні)

[Сучасна українська літературна мова](http://pidruchniki.com/1212012440560/dokumentoznavstvo/kategoriya_perehidnostineperehidnosti)

Отже, "заощаджувати на чомусь" - вживання перехідного дієслова з прийменником в якості неперехідного. Допустима форма, унормований мовний процес.